# nested class - get as public for all, set only for outer class

Tags: c#

How can I set modifiers? I'd like to have 'get' in nested class as public for all, set only for outer class? 
Errors:

> The property of indexer 'Cart.CartItem.Quantity' cannot be used in
>   this context because set accessor is inaccessible
>   'Cart.CartItem.CartItem(Guid itemId, string name, decimal price, int
>   quantity)' is inaccessible due to its protection level

Code:

```
public class Cart
{
    public List<CartItem> CartItems { get; private set; }
    public int TotalQuantity => CartItems.Sum(x => x.Quantity);
    public decimal TotalPrice => CartItems.Sum(x => x.Price * x.Quantity);

    public Cart()
    {
        CartItems = new List<CartItem>();
    }

    public void AddItem(Guid itemId, string name, decimal price)
    {
        CartItem cartItem = CartItems.Find(x => x.ItemId == itemId);

        if (cartItem != null)
        {
            cartItem.Quantity += 1;
        }
        else
        {
            CartItems.Add(new CartItem(itemId, name, price, 1));
        }
    }

    public class CartItem
    {
        public Guid ItemId { get; private set; }
        public string Name { get; private set; }
        public int Quantity { get; private set; }
        public decimal Price { get; private set; }

        private CartItem(Guid itemId, string name, decimal price, int quantity)
        {
            ItemId = itemId;
            Name = name;
            Price = price;
            Quantity = quantity;            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the code that generates this error?

Comment: @ZoharPeled, I think here is an error => `cartItem.Quantity += 1;` because `set` is private for `Quantity ` in `CartItem` class

Comment: @er-sho Yes, you're probably correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not quite following the reasons to use a Nested Type.

> Nested Type has access to private fields defined in the enclosing type

Look at the link about [Dos and Donts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/nested-types)

> X AVOID publicly exposed nested types. The only exception to this is if variables of the nested type need to be declared only in rare scenarios such as subclassing or other advanced customization scenarios.
>
> X DO NOT use nested types if the type is likely to be referenced outside of the containing type.

So the proper way to do it would be to keep the class private and the members public, so the Nested Type members and fields are only accessible to the enclosing type

```
public class Cart {
    List<CartItem> CartItems { get; set; }
    public int TotalQuantity => CartItems.Sum(x => x.Quantity);
    public decimal TotalPrice => CartItems.Sum(x => x.Price * x.Quantity);

    public Cart() {
        CartItems = new List<CartItem>();
    }

    public void AddItem(Guid itemId, string name, decimal price) {
        CartItem cartItem = CartItems.Find(x => x.ItemId == itemId);

        if (cartItem != null) {
            cartItem.Quantity += 1;
        } else {
            CartItems.Add(new CartItem(itemId, name, price, 1));
        }
    }

    class CartItem {
        public Guid ItemId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }

        public CartItem(Guid itemId, string name, decimal price, int quantity) {
            ItemId = itemId;
            Name = name;
            Price = price;
            Quantity = quantity;
        }
    }
}

class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        var test = new Cart.CartItem(Guid.Empty, "", 0.0m, 10); // Error CS0122  'Cart.CartItem' is inaccessible due to its protection level 


    }
}
```

Comment: It should compile except for the code in `Main`, which will show the commented error